# Can I create a menu button somewhere other than the options menu in android?

Tags: android, interface, button, menu

I've read through all of the android documentation that I can find but I'm still not clear on whether a button can be added to an application for an android device somewhere outside of an options/context menu. It seems like all of the menu buttons are only accessible either from a tab bar at the bottom or the menu button on the device. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but you can use a Button widget in an activity anywhere you want, just like any other widget type. See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html